# Literature SE blog?

Tags: discussion, blog

This might be too early into the public beta to ask this, but should we have an un-official blog, like Worldbuilding.SE does?

Comment: I have already established a wiki: https://literature.miraheze.org/wiki/Main_Page

Comment: "This might be too early" -- *far too early...*

Answer (score 7):

### **Yes, this sounds like a great idea ...**

Literature is a topic which would fit into a blog-post model better than a lot of technology-related subjects. On a Literature.SE blog, we could post up regular book reviews, as well as extended discussions of things which might not fit well into a strict Q&A format. If some of our members are going to literary conventions, they could write up reports and post them on our blog.

### **... but maybe not yet.**

However, the site is still very young and we have a lot of other things to sort out more urgently: meta discussions around our scope and tagging system, fleshing out our question base with more questions on more topics, and getting some of those pesky unanswered questions solved. Plus we're not very big yet. It's only day 2 of public beta; we still have fewer than 500 members and only one Popular Question so far. I'm not sure either if we can spare the manpower to set up and maintain a community blog, or if it would get enough eyeballs to be worth doing, at this point.

Comment: What is a popular question?

Comment: @Benjamin http://literature.stackexchange.com/help/badges/26/popular-question